# oauth2ClientContext is not getting injected

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

The application is not starting as there are two candidate beans. I am getting the below error when starting the application.

```
***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 0 of method oauth2RestTemplate in com.classpath.assetservice.AssetServiceApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'oauth2ClientContext' in 'OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.RequestScopedConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth Client ID did not find security.oauth2.client.client-id property
    - Bean method 'oauth2ClientContext' in 'OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.SingletonScopedConfiguration' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.ClientCredentialsCondition.NoWebApplication @ConditionalOnWebApplication found 'session' scope and did not find reactive web application classes; NestedCondition on OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration.ClientCredentialsCondition.ClientCredentialsConfigured @ConditionalOnProperty (security.oauth2.client.grant-type=client_credentials) did not find property 'grant-type'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Below is my `Controller` class

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableResourceServer
public class AssetServiceApplication {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(
            OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
            OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AssetServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Below is the corresponding dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue by adding the following property in application.yml file

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8901/auth/user
    client: # This property (client.grant-type)
      grant-type: client_credentials
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the Spring documentation you can simply add `@EnableOAuth2Client` and Spring Boot will create an `OAuth2ClientContext` for you. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-custom-user-info-client) for more details.